# Do extra zeros change the coordinates for decimal degrees?

Tags: gps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

At my work we require contractors to submit work reports in decimal degrees with 6 decimal places, i.e. the location of where they paved roads or put in a road sign.

The question is, contractors have told me that when they take the coordinates of certain locations, there only is 4 decimal places. They argue that adding 2 zeros on the end will change the location.

```
i.e. 38.8897°, -77.0089° vs. 38.889700°, -77.008900°
```

I realize for this case it doesn't, but does this hold true for all cases?

Comment: It asserts a precision not captured by the measurement, but it doesn't "change the location".